# Please help me understand the deletion by "community" and their rationale for deleting this question

Tags: discussion, support

Please help me understand the deletion by "community" and their rationale for deleting this question:

> [In the Catholic Church, what rules are to be followed when
>   interpreting the Bible?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/35542/in-the-catholic-church-what-rules-are-to-be-followed-when-interpreting-the-bibl)
>
> It is well known that the Catholic Church does not rely solely on Holy
>   Scripture when discussing matters of faith and belief; it adds what is
>   known as Sacred Tradition as well, and the Church Magisterium, the
>   authority which the Church holds to be inherited from the apostles,
>   and by which it interprets both Scripture and Tradition.
>
> There is also a historic difference between Catholicism and many
>   Protestant denominations in that (as I understand it) many Protestant
>   denominations encourage not only personal reading of Scripture, but
>   personal interpretation of it—whereas Catholicism is strongly
>   against interpretation that does not originate with, or at least agree
>   with, the Magisterium.
>
> All of which raises the following question: In the Catholic Church, is
>   there an accepted procedure to be used in order to interpret the
>   meaning of Holy Scripture (in agreement with Tradition, for example)?
>   Or guidelines to be adhered to? Patristic writings to be aware of?
>   Prayers to be said? Etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a feature of all Stack Exchange sites to [remove poorly-received questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/1438).

My suggestion would be to consider carefully the [final edit](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/35542/revisions), which came too late to avoid collecting two downvotes. The version that collected those votes read:

> In the Catholic Church, which is the sound rule for biblical interpretation?
>
> The answer sought will first identify *senses* of Scripture according to Church Tradition.

This is unclear and far too terse.

Comment: Any chance to provide me with a sample proposal to assist me in re-asking this question?